# Check if statement validity row by row and assign specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column (C) that is blank and will get assigned a value based on the type of data that is in the column to the right of it (D, E, F). You can see example scenarios in the if statements below.

What's the most efficient way to go through the range and assign each row's "value" based on different parameters?

```
function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.createMenu('Invite Automation'
        .addItem('Assign Rows', 'labelRows')
        .addToUi();
}

function labelRows() {

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var index = range.getRow();
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var getType = sheet.getRange(index, 4).getValue();

    var colC = sheet.getRange("C:C");
    var colCValues = colC.getValues();

    const labelRow = sheet.getRange(index, 3);

    for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++) {


            if (getType == "Apple" || getType == "Orange") {
                labelRow.setValue("Fruit");
            }


        }

    }
    
}
```

Here is an example spreadsheet:

| Column C/3 | Column D/4 |
| --- | --- |
| Assignment: | Type: |
|  | Apple |
|  | Orange |

In the menu, it would read through column 4 by checking the if statements, and if true, assigns a certain value (in this example, if "Apple" or "Orange" are found, it assigns "Fruit" in column C.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to insert a value in one column based on the value in another column

First, your current script had a few issues:

```js
function labelRows() {

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var index = range.getRow(); // range has not been defined yet
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var getType = sheet.getRange(index, 4).getValue(); // since range has not been defined, index will also be undefined.

    var colC = sheet.getRange("C:C");
    var colCValues = colC.getValues();

    const labelRow = sheet.getRange(index, 3); // Again here you will have undefined issues

    for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++) {


            if (getType == "Apple" || getType == "Orange") {
                labelRow.setValue("Fruit"); // Again here you will have undefined issues
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Apart from these mistakes, this script, even if it did work, would be quite slow.

The most efficient way to process data in a sheet is to first get all the values into memory (that is, into Apps Script), and then work on the values *within* Apps Script, and then dump all the values back into the sheet at the end.

This is opposed to a common approach of getting or setting single values one by one, which sets up a long delay because for each iteration, the execution has to deal with the relatively slow process of reading from / writing to the spreadsheet.

You can use `getDataRange` and `getValues`, to get a large 2D array. Which then allows you to use all the native JavaScript properties and methods related to arrays. Like `length`.

Here is the modified approach.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Invite Automation')
    .addItem('Assign Rows', 'labelRows')
    .addToUi()
}

function labelRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the whole used range of the sheet.
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  // Get all the values in the sheet
  let values = range.getValues();
  // Get the length of the values array which is equal to the number of rows
  const numRows = values.length

  // Loop through all rows in values array
  for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    // get the type in column D (index 3)
    const type = values[row][3]
    // check if value is equal to:
    if (type == "Apple" || type == "Orange" || type == "Banana") {
      // set column C value to "Fruit"
      values[row][2] = "Fruit"
    }
  }
  // Finally, take the original range and set values of the modified values array
  range.setValues(values)
}
```

You can then add conditions to this line:

```js
 if (type == "Apple" || type == "Orange" || type == "Banana") {
```

There is also another way to check conditions. You could keep all the conditions in an array like this

```js
const fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
```

And then the condition would look like this:

```js
if ( fruits.includes(type) ) {
```

Which may be more practical for you if you have many different categories or conditions.

## References

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getDataRange())
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues())
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [array.inclues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)